# Storing of Wifi Passwords

Tags: passwords, wifi, keychain

Is there any way to retrieve wifi passwords stored in keychain in objective C? I could not find the answer to this solution. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless networks passwords are stored in the system keychain (or login keychain, depending on the OS version) - here's a stackexchange question on this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/56130/how-to-find-wifi-password-on-my-mac-which-is-already-connected.
From ObjectiveC you can use the Apple provided API to access the keychain: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html. Particularly for your task, I recommend using the https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecKeychainFindGenericPassword function.